# Run bash script in current directory Linux

Tags: linux, bash, cd, pwd

Why can't I run a bash script in the current directory I'm in?
Whenever I run the script the commands are executed in the home directory.
The only answers I found are included below.
I do use the zsh shell. I don't know if that changes anything.
Thanks in advance!

What I have tried so far:

---

#!/bin/bash

touch test.txt

---

#!/bin/bash

cd $PWD

touch test.txt

---

#!/bin/bash

variable = $PWD

cd $variable

touch test.txt

---

#!/bin/bash

variable= `pwd`

cd $variable

touch test.txt

---

#!/bin/bash
cd -

touch test.txt

---

If I run the script for example from /home/user/dir1/dir1.1 the test.txt file is created in the home directory (/home/user) and I get redirected to the home directory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in bash there are two things to do:

1. ensure that the shell script file is saved properly and is chmod'd to be an executable.

To do so, save the file (e.g. `script.sh`)  with the code you want, and then run `chmod +x script.sh` to make linux understand that this file is an executable.

2. call the executable properly using the `./script.sh` command.  alternatively, you can also call the script from remote folder by calling it using the absolute path the script is in (e.g. `/folder/folder/folder/script.sh`).

This should execute the file.  from there, it's about your code and if you need help there, please update your question.